# Graph programming in Scheme

Tags: graph, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I'm new to Scheme, have been using MIT Scheme for sometime now. I'm trying to understand how to implement popular graph algorithms like the shortest path algorithms, BFS, DFS. Are there any tutorials that could help me out understand the recursion that'd be involved, along with the appropriate data structures? I have tried Googling my way around, but that didn't end up giving me good results.

**EDIT**: I apologize for not being more specific earlier. My question was pertaining to traversing the whole graph, and not finding the path between a *start* and *goal* node. So, given a graph *G(V, E)*, where *V* is the vertex set and *E* is the edge set, starting from any node *n*, what is the path generated so that at the end of this traversal, all nodes are visited.

Most implementations that I found while Googling were the ones with the *start* and *goal* node. My version (one of the answers), chooses one vertex, and visits all others.

Take for example, the following graph:-

```
1 ----> 2           5
       /|          /|
      / |         / |
     /  |        /  |
    /   |       /   |
   /    |      /    | 
  4<----3 <---6     7
```

This *DAG* has (4->2), (2->3), (5->6) and (5->7), which I unable to represent in the diagram. :-)

The Path traversed starting from **1** could be:

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time, but I got it working finally! My output is the sequence in which the nodes would've been visited in the traversal through DFS.

Note that I am still only learning Scheme, and my programming approach might not be the best. If you find something wrong, incorrect or something that can be expressed better, leave a comment!

```
    (define (dfs graph)
       (define (dfshelper g unvisited stack path)
          (cond
             ((null? unvisited) path)
                ((null? stack)
                   (dfshelper g
                              unvisited 
                              (append (list (caar unvisited)) stack) 
                              path))
                ((memq (car stack) path) (dfshelper g
                                                    unvisited 
                                                    (cdr stack) 
                                                    path))
                (else (dfshelper g
                                 (cdr unvisited) 
                                 (append (car (neighbours (car stack) g)) (cdr stack)) 
                                 (append path (list (car stack)))))))

   (define (neighbours node g)
      (cond
         ((null? g) '())
         ((equal? node (caar g)) (cdar g))
         (else (neighbours node 
                           (cdr g)))))

   (dfshelper graph  graph '() '()))
```

Sample input could be: (dfs '((1 (2)) (2 (3)) (3 (4)) (4 (2)) (5 (3 6)) (6 ())))

Comment: I'm curious about what you're trying to code up.  Specifically, a search algorithm usually involves searching for a goal or target, but it looks like your program does not. Some purpose statements, contracts, and test cases would help a bunch!

Comment: John, I have added a short summary to my question! Let me know if I am missing something!

Answer (score 4):

Breadth-first and Depth-first search both occur as examples in [How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org), starting in section [28](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-35.html#node_chap_28). I think that this will probably help you most specifically with your question about the uses of recursion in graph processing.

Comment: The traversal described there has a start and a goal node, and ends if the goal node is found. The problem that I'm facing while implementing a full DFS, is that the "visited" list is not propagated to higher levels of recursion.

Comment: Sure, that's valid. In order to solve that, you'd want a searcher that returns either a valid path *or* a list of all the nodes visited so far. This would allow you to avoid visiting the same nodes twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you represent graphs like this, i.e. as a list of names of nodes and the names of their neighbors:

```
(define Graph 
  '((A (B E))
    (B (E F))
    (C (D)))
```

that has the advantage that you can even represent cyclic graphs without resorting to destructive modification of your data structure (`set-cdr!` etc.), provided you allow multiple entries in the list for each key.

Alternately, you could store not just the names but the full representation of each neighbor in a list, so that you can walk the graph without doing any name lookups:

```
(define node-name car)
(define node-children cdr)
(define node-first-child cadr)

(node-first-child (node-first-child node1))
```

To make a cyclic graph this way though, you'd need to use `set!` or some variant.  So the best representation really depends on the application.

Comment: Thanks gcbenison, your graph representation was helpful!